# undefined variable on ansible_facts

Tags: ansible

I am trying to wait for a service to start before continuing my playbook.  I am using the documentation below as a starting point.  It doesnt matter what service I use to test this with I keep getting the same error message.  I have tried to input different well known services in the debug output and the same output.  I have printed out the entire ansible_facts.services and verified that the service I want to run this against is there.  What am I missing?

https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2022/01/12/how-to-wait-until-service-is-running-inside-ansible-playbook/

> fatal: [rke-master01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option
> with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no
> attribute 'rke2-server'\n\nThe error appears to be in
> '/Users/jolim/Documents/Ansible/roles/rke2/tasks/main.yml': line 139,
> column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
> syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name:
> services dump\n      ^ here\n"}

```
- name: "Wait until rke2-server service is running"
  ansible.builtin.service_facts:
  register: temp__service_facts
  # until: temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services.rke2-server.state == 'running'
  # retries: 10
  # delay: 6

- name: services dump
  debug:
    msg:  "{{ temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services['rke2-server'].state }}"
```

The output of the services where rke2-server is located is:

```
"rke2-agent.service": {
    "name": "rke2-agent.service",
    "source": "systemd",
    "state": "stopped",
    "status": "disabled"
},
"rke2-server.service": {
    "name": "rke2-server.service",
    "source": "systemd",
    "state": "running",
    "status": "enabled"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write this:

```
msg:  "{{ temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services[ssh] | to_nice_json }}"
```

You are trying to look up a value in the `temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services` dictionary using the *value of a variable* named `ssh`. There is no such variable, so you can the `'ssh` is undefined` error.

To refer to a literal string, put it in quotes:

```
msg:  "{{ temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services['ssh'] | to_nice_json }}"
```

Or just continue using dot notation isntead:

```
msg:  "{{ temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services.ssh | to_nice_json }}"
```

The two syntaxes are equivalent.

Comment: This seems to work with ssh, but when I try to do the actual service I want to use which is "rke2-server" I get the same thing.  Is there an issue with the service having a "-" or something.  I know that rke2-server exists in the facts.

Comment: If you have a `-` in the name you need to use the first version (`services['rke2-server']`). If you're still getting an error, then the next would be to add a debug task that outputs the contents of `temp__service_facts.ansible_facts.services` and include that in your question.

Comment: updated the question with the output from services.  Attempted the suggestion before posting the question and still getting the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  It appears that the rke2-server is called rke2-server.service so I have to use `(services['rke2-server.service'])` to get it to work.